# Complex cucumber tags from command line with AND, OR operations is not working

Tags: maven, command-line, cucumber

I'm running cucumber scenarios from command line

Below command works fine for me

mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @Admin --tags  @sanity"

When i run complex command and its not working

I want o run cucumber scenarios with tags (admin and sanity) or (employee and sanity)

mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags (@Admin and @sanity) or (@Employee and @sanity)"

I'm getting below error, when i run above command

initializationError(test.java.runner.TestRunner)  Time elapsed: 0.003 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory: ../project_folder/and

Comment: Enclose the tag option in single quotes. Try this `mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags '(@Admin and @sanity) or (@Employee and @sanity)'"`

Comment: @Grasshopper check https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1596 for some nuances in the quotes needed. Depending on maven version the double and single quotes need to be swapped.

Comment: @mpkorstanje Had tried on 2.12.4 and 2.22.2 on Windows and it worked. Tried mvn command with `-Dtest`for specific runner and `-Dcucumber.options` as above from cmd for maven version 2.5 till milestone 3 ones. Only fails for 2.12 and 2.19. That also for `-Dtest` option. In 2.5 no error but does not filter scenarios. Guess it is OS dependent as issue mentions Linux.

Comment: Owh that's even better. :D I am using Linux and you have to swap the qoute symbols there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The --tags expression parsing is fairly primitive, and I'd recommend looking at

```
cucumber --help
```

Since the expression you want is ((@Admin || @Employee) && @sanity), you could try:

```
--tags @Admin,@Employee --tags @sanity
```

The comma represents a logical or, and specifying multiple `--tags` arguments represents a logical and.

Note that the words "or" or "and" is interpreted by the cucumber argument parser as the names of feature files to include in the tests.